# keeping the path to file in thumb drive the same accross all os's

Tags: linux, windows, macos, path, usb-flash-drive

I have a typical usb stick and whenever I plug it in to different os's I get different names for the stick

In Mac it is called "NO NAME"

In windows it is called "E"

In Linux it is called "EA94-E242"

Is their a way to manually set the name of my thumdrive to ALWAYS (regardless of the os) have the same name?

The goal here is to be able to plug my thumbdrive in to any of my computers which run Mac Linux and Windows (depending on the computer) and have the same path to a python file I am working to be able to run on boot for a pentest..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks All

Comment: I believe its called a *"stable name"* or *"consistent naming"*. At least that's what I've heard it called for ethernet adaptors (cf., [Consistent Network Device Naming in Linux](http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/consistent_network_device_naming_in_linux.pdf)). I don't believe there's a way to do it. You may have better luck finding an answer on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).